# How to move different value of src column to different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following data

```
sk_patient  casenumber  src     status  pen_dt
-1           2345       POPDB   CLOSED  2012-01-01
-1           235        POPDB   CLOSED  2012-01-01
-1           245        JCARE   CLOSED  2012-01-02
1244         2          POPDB   CLOSED  2012-01-01
273          2345       POPDB   CLOSED  2012-03-04
1244         23         JCARE   CLOSED  2012-05-02
```

Which needs to be converted as following on the basis of different `src` column value.

```
sk_patient  casenumber1  src1    status1    pen_dt1     casenumber2 src2  status2   pen_dt2
    -1       2345        POPDB   CLOSED     2012-01-01   245        JCARE  CLOSED   2012-01-02
    -1       235         POPDB   CLOSED     2012-01-01   NULL       NULL   NULL     NULL
    1244     2           POPDB   CLOSED     2012-01-01   23        JCARE   CLOSED    2012-05-02
    273      2345        POPDB   CLOSED     2012-03-04   NULL       NULL   NULL     NULL
```

For example,

for `-1` we have 3 rows, but two of them has same `src`, so we will them as it is, but 3 row has different value. So, that needs to be moved to `src2` column and associated column values as well.

There will be minimum 1 and maximum 3 different `src` can be associated for any specific `sk_patient`.

**===Update===**

Till now, I was able to do following

```
seq sk_patient  casenumber  src     status  pen_dt
2   -1           2345       POPDB   CLOSED  2012-01-01
2   -1           235        POPDB   CLOSED  2012-01-01
1   -1           245        JCARE   CLOSED  2012-01-02
2   1244         2          POPDB   CLOSED  2012-01-01
1   273          2345       POPDB   CLOSED  2012-03-04
1   1244         23         JCARE   CLOSED  2012-05-02
```

I have used following query

```
select dense_rank() 
       over(partition by sk_patient order by sk_patient, src) as seq, 
       * from patient
```

Could anyone help me to move value as above example ?

Comment: There is no identity column? How can we order the data?

Comment: @Wanderer Ordering is not required. But, solution sake, we can use `src` column for ordering ???

Comment: @Matt Sequentially traversing existing row for same `sk_patient` if `src` column is same, then won't do anything otherwise move to 2nd, if found different again then move to 3rd.

Comment: @Matt I'm not specific to ordering, so different `src` value should be part of 2nd and then 3rd column and this is what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: @Matt Agree with you point. I think we need to have some ordering.

Comment: @Matt No, maximum 3 src means 3 different source. Example, `sk_patient=-1` has 3 rows but 2 different `src`. Yes, it might be possible to have 5-10 rows having 3 src. But ofcourse few rows will have same src.

Comment: @Matt You could share your solution I will take it forward whatever changes are required.

Comment: sorry I am done with the game if you are not willing to give a basic ordering

Comment: @Matt we could use `src` value for ordering. Example, `JCARE` would be `1` , `POPDB` would be `3` and `MSR` would be `2` (which is not mentioned in above example).

Comment: @unnamed if you have 10 rows as you have said in another comment I max 3 srcs that would hardly ever give you a 2nd or 3rd src and the results would be almost entirely the same as your original table. Seems to me that you want an answer haven't shown what you have tried and aren't including your actual requirements. It's the kind of answer no one can get right. You said you can adopt/change someone else's code so as I said before search for gaps and islands and then use conditional aggregation or self joins to transform table the way you want

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tp1.sk_patient,
       tp1.casenumber casenumber1,
       tp1.src src1,
       tp1.status status1,
       tp1.pen_dt pen_dt1,
       tp2.casenumber2,
       tp2.src2,
       tp2.status2,
       tp2.pen_dt2
  FROM t_patient tp1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT sk_patient,
                          MAX(CASE WHEN rnum = 1 THEN casenumber END) casenumber1,
                          MAX(CASE WHEN rnum = 1 THEN src END) src1,
                          MAX(CASE WHEN rnum = 1 THEN status END) status1,
                          MAX(CASE WHEN rnum = 1 THEN pen_dt END) pen_dt1,
                          MAX(CASE WHEN rnum = 2 THEN casenumber END) casenumber2,
                          MAX(CASE WHEN rnum = 2 THEN src END) src2,
                          MAX(CASE WHEN rnum = 2 THEN status END) status2,
                          MAX(CASE WHEN rnum = 2 THEN pen_dt END) pen_dt2
                     FROM (SELECT *,
                                  DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sk_patient ORDER BY src DESC) rnum
                             FROM t_patient
                          ) t
                    GROUP BY sk_patient
                  ) tp2
    ON tp1.sk_patient = tp2.sk_patient
   AND tp1.casenumber = tp2.casenumber1
   AND tp1.src = tp2.src1
 WHERE tp1.src != 'JCARE'
```

Result

```
sk_patient  casenumber1 src1    status1 pen_dt1     casenumber2 src2    status2 pen_dt2
-1          2345        POPDB   CLOSED  2012-01-01  245         JCARE   CLOSED  2012-01-02
-1          235         POPDB   CLOSED  2012-01-01  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL
1244        2           POPDB   CLOSED  2012-01-01  23          JCARE   CLOSED  2012-05-02
273         2345        POPDB   CLOSED  2012-03-04  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL
```